# How to pin and unpin an element using js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So basically I have a side nav on a page I'm working on and I'm trying to pin it on scroll and unpin when it reaches a certain point. Now the purpose of this question isn't to get direct answers only, I'll also like a bit of explanation as to why my code isn't working.

The code is all good when I'm pinning it to the page but I want it to unpin when it reaches the footer section, that's where I'm having a bit of headache.

I tried this:

HTML

```
<div class="header"></div>
<div class="side-nav"></div>
<div>Rest of page content</div>
<div class="footer"></div>
```

JS

```
  function pinElement() {
     var products = document.querySelector('.rest-of-page'),
       scroll = window.scrollY,
       nav = document.querySelector('.side-nav'),
       navTop = nav.offsetTop
       header = document.querySelector('.header'),
       offset = header.clientHeight,
       end = products.clientHeight + products.offsetTop; 


       if (scroll >= navTop) {
            nav.style.position = 'fixed';
            nav.style.top = offset;
        } else if (scroll < navTop) {
            nav.style.position = 'relative';
        } else {
            if(scroll >= end){
               nav.style.position = 'relative';
            }
        }
  }        
       document.addEventListener('scroll', pinElement)
```

Now the issue I'm having it doesn't unpin when it reaches "end" variable instead it scrolls past it and unpins somewhere near the bottom. I want to understand why this happens and find a proper way of fixing this.
 Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "pin"?

Comment: make an element's position fixed on the page

Comment: @HackAfro than say so :)

Comment: @HackAfro, I've made a significant edit to my answer that you'll probably find useful, please let me know if that works.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not that your conditional isn't reaching `if(scroll >= end)` since that will be true even if `scroll >= navTop`.

What should `nav.style.top` be if it's below `end`? Your original conditional always set it to `offset`.

**Set `nav.style.top = offset;` to the top of `end` when the user scrolls past `end` otherwise, you're setting `nav.style.top` to `offset`.**

```
if (scroll >= navTop  && !(scroll >= end)) {
        nav.style.position = 'fixed';
        nav.style.top = offset;
    } else if (scroll < navTop) {
        nav.style.position = 'relative';
        //You may wish to set nav.style.top here too since it's ambiguous otherwise
}
if(scroll >= end){
           nav.style.position = 'relative';
           nav.style.top = end.style.top; //or where ever you want it to be
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your if/else statement the last condition never get reached.
I have amended your code to make your last condition reachable.

```
function pinElement() {
     var products = document.querySelector('.rest-of-page'),
       scroll = window.scrollY,
       nav = document.querySelector('.side-nav'),
       navTop = nav.offsetTop
       header = document.querySelector('.header'),
       offset = header.clientHeight,
       end = products.clientHeight + products.offsetTop; 


       if (scroll >= navTop && scroll < end) {
            nav.style.position = 'fixed';
            nav.style.top = offset;
        } else if (scroll < navTop) {
            nav.style.position = 'relative';
        } else {
            if(scroll >= end){
               nav.style.position = 'relative';
            }
        }
  }        
  document.addEventListener('scroll', pinElement)
```